# Required modifications for water level control

Tags: microcontroller

I have a small doubt about the circuit present in the following page:

http://www.electronicshub.org/water-level-indicator/

The circuit present in the above page helps to just detect and indicate the water level present in the container. But I want to modify that circuit in such a way that after reaching the certain limit it should indicate and as well as it should automatically control the level of water. For that purpose, what are the modifications to be done to that circuit?

And also, Is it possible to use any type of microcontroller for that circuit or any particular microcontroller is required for that project?

Kindly clarify my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to see you do some research (or show that you have). You would need some way of controlling the level from the microcontroller, either a drain valve, inlet valve or both. Any microconttroller should do.

Comment: Another problem with the circuit is that, in the long run, it will stop working. After a while impurities in the water will allow corrosion of the exposed wires, and the current flow will drop to zero. The fix for this is to excite the sensors with AC (no DC voltage at all, not just a square wave). Or, if you like, you can gold-plate the exposed wire, and even that won't work in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

To make the fill control for the water tank you should be able to use the same microcontroller as the one shown in the example. In that case an Atmel AVR was used.

The circuit would require the addition of an output from the AVR that would go to a buffer circuit that would in turn be used to turn an electronically controlled water valve on and off.

Then the software if the AVR would have to be modified to control the fill valve ON/OFF state based upon the level sensor states. The simplest scheme would simply turn the valve ON when the level 9 was not active and then when the water filled enough so that once the level 9 changed state the valve would be turned to the OFF state. An alternative would be to select some other lower level to use for detecting of the valve ON state and then turn OFF when level 9 showed the tank was once again full.

The fill valve usage assumes that there is a pressurized source of water from which the water is supplied to the tank. On the other hand if a pump was required to move water from say a pond into the tank then the pump ON/OFF could be controlled in place of the fill valve.